# Unable to create tables - mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm working on a personal project of mine, and currently I'm working on the installation script. However, it isn't working as it should, as it should currently create two tables with some columns.

Here's the code:

```
<?php

$db = "table";
$user = "root";
$pass = "xxxxxxxxx";

$dothemagic = new mysqli("localhost",$user,$pass,$db);
if(!$dothemagic){
    die("Teit jotain pahasti väärin! ".mysql_error());
}
else {
    echo "Yhteys tietokantaan luotu!<br>";}

$product = "CREATE TABLE product
    (
    ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    Name varchar(80),
    Description varchar(6000),
    Price varchar(10)
    )
";

$kategory = "CREATE TABLE product
    (
    ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    Name varchar(80),
    Description varchar(6000)
    )
";
if(!mysqli_query($product,$dothemagic)){
    echo "Taulua tuote ei voitu luoda! Tarkista asetuksesi!<br>";
}
else{echo "Taulu tuote on luotu!<br>";}

if(!mysqli_query($kategory,$dothemagic)){
    echo "Taulua kategoria ei voitu luoda! Tarkista asetuksesi!<br>";
}
else{echo "Taulu kategoria on luotu!<br>";}
```

When I navigate to the script location, I get the following text:

```
Yhteys tietokantaan luotu!
Taulua tuote ei voitu luoda! Tarkista asetuksesi!
Taulua kategoria ei voitu luoda! Tarkista asetuksesi!
```

So in english, it connects to database, but it's unable to create the tables. As It's running on root, it should have all the rights... What's wrong?

Comment: Use `mysqli_error()` to get the respective error message.

Comment: return the error from the db, then you would know what was wrong.

Comment: Are you sure that the table doesn't get created? `CREATE TABLE` does not return a result set.

Comment: Both tables are called `product`. Is that just a typo here?

Comment: generally speaking, you should NEVER use the root account for anything but administering the db server. use a limited-permissions account for any client-side connections.

Comment: @njk `mysqli_query` only returns `false` on failure.

Comment: @jeroen yes, just a typo.

Comment: @MarcB yeah I know, I'm always using a different account for different project.

Comment: @njk yeah, they aren't created. I'm looking at the database ATM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you've got the order of your arguments incorrect. As per the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) the `$link` should be first. You appear to have it in the second position here.

It would be harder to get this wrong if you used the object-oriented style.

Comment: Well, whatever you call your database handle. I believe here you've called it `$dothemagic` for whatever reason.

Comment: Oh thanks! Again, I see how using w3schools as a reference will cause problems.

Comment: As w3schools is providing this on their mysql tutorial.. `mysql_query($sql,$con);`

Comment: You should block w3schools from your browser for your own safety. It's a hazardously bad resource. Also `mysqli_query` and `mysql_query` are not the same thing.

Comment: I know. Is there any resource similar to w3schools but with up-to-date information?

Comment: Using low-level database calls even with [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) is an out of date practice, so you won't see many good tutorials for that sort of thing. Better would be to pick a framework like [Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/), [CodeIgnighter](http://codeignighter.com/), [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/), [FuelPHP](http://fuelphp.com/) or any of the other widely supported [PHP frameworks](http://phpframeworks.com/) to provide a foundation for your application.

Answer (score -1):

The CREATE TABLE statement is used to create a table in MySQL.
We must add the CREATE TABLE statement to the mysqli_query() function to execute the command.

Comment: The question has an accepted answer, and is 11 months old. It doesn't need an answer like this.